# How to set the index in an array when filling in data?

Tags: arrays

```
# the available data
y = array(rnorm(165))
origins = 130:157

# define a vector where result will be saved
x = array(0,c(length(origins),1))

# define the denominator for MASE
for (origin in origins){
  for (t in 2:origin){
  x[] = sum(abs(y[t]-yl[t-1]))
  }
}
```

Anyone who can help me set the index in "x[]" so that the corresponding cell in "x" could be filled by the calculation in y? In other words, I want to fill in all results in x rather than the last one only. Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to also tag the language you're using.

Comment: I am so sorry about that. The language is R. Thank you very much.